# How to merge Publisher one by one in Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

The following codes will output

1,2,3,4,5, then 300,400, 500

Is there a way to emit one by one like

1, 300, 2, 400, 3, 500, 4, 5

```swift
print("\n* Demonstrating Merge")
let publisher1 = [1,2,3,4,5].publisher
let publisher2 = [300,400,500].publisher

let mergedPublishersSubscription = Publishers
    .Merge(publisher1, publisher2)
    .sink { value in
        print("Merge: subscription received value \(value)")
}
```

Comment: What kind of publishers are you dealing with in your real code? Your code behaves like this because you are merging publishers created from collections, which (I think) publishes everything synchronously. As it currently stands, you should just merge the arrays first, then create the publisher. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can do it with a custom publisher.  I've not tested this thoroughly but it works at least with the simple sample test case you've provided.

```
import Cocoa
import Combine
import Foundation

struct InterleavedPublisher<P1,P2> : Publisher where
P1: Publisher,
P2: Publisher,
P1.Output == P2.Output,
P1.Failure == P2.Failure
{
    typealias Output = P1.Output
    typealias Failure = P1.Failure

    enum WhichPub {
        case pub1
        case pub2
    }

    let publisher1 : P1
    let publisher2 : P2

    init(publisher1 : P1, publisher2: P2) {
        self.publisher1 = publisher1
        self.publisher2 = publisher2
    }

    class InterleavedSubscription : Subscription {
        var takeFrom = WhichPub.pub1
        var pub1subscription : Subscription?
        var pub2subscription : Subscription?
        var combineIdentifier = CombineIdentifier()
        var pentUp : Subscribers.Demand = .none

        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            switch demand {
                case .unlimited:
                    self.pentUp = .unlimited
                case .none:
                    self.pentUp = .none
                default:
                    self.pentUp += demand
            }

            switch pentUp {
                case .none:
                    ()
                case .unlimited:
                    requestFromNext()

                default:
                    requestFromNext()
                    pentUp -= 1
            }
        }

        private func requestFromNext() {
            if takeFrom == .pub1 {
                pub1subscription?.request(.max(1))
                if nil != pub2subscription {
                    takeFrom = .pub2
                }
            } else {
                pub2subscription?.request(.max(1))
                if nil != pub1subscription {
                    takeFrom = .pub1
                }
            }
        }

        func cancel() {
            self.pub1subscription = nil
            self.pub2subscription = nil
        }

        init<S>(
            publisher1 : P1,
            publisher2 : P2,
            subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, P1.Failure == S.Failure, P1.Output == S.Input {

            let subscriber1 = AnySubscriber<P1.Output, P1.Failure>(
                receiveSubscription: {
                    self.pub1subscription = $0
                },
                receiveValue: { value in
                    subscriber.receive(value)

                    self.takeFrom = .pub2
                    self.requestFromNext()
                    return .none
                },
                receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    switch completion {
                        case .finished:
                            self.pub1subscription = nil
                            if(self.pub2subscription == nil) {
                                subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                                self.cancel()
                            } else {
                                if(nil != self.pub2subscription) {
                                    self.takeFrom = .pub2
                                }

                                self.requestFromNext()
                            }
                        case .failure(_):
                            subscriber.receive(completion: completion)
                            self.cancel()
                    }
                })

            let subscriber2 = AnySubscriber<P2.Output, P2.Failure>(
                receiveSubscription: {
                    self.pub2subscription = $0
                },
                receiveValue: { value in
                    subscriber.receive(value)

                    if(nil != self.pub1subscription) {
                        self.takeFrom = .pub1
                    }
                    self.requestFromNext()
                    return .none
                },
                receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    switch completion {
                        case .finished:
                            self.pub2subscription = nil
                            if nil == self.pub1subscription {
                                subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                                self.cancel()
                            } else {
                                self.takeFrom = .pub1
                                self.requestFromNext()
                            }
                        case .failure(_):
                            subscriber.receive(completion: completion)
                            self.cancel()
                    }
                })

            publisher1.receive(subscriber: subscriber1)
            publisher2.receive(subscriber: subscriber2)
        }
    }

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, P1.Failure == S.Failure, P1.Output == S.Input {

        let subscription = InterleavedSubscription(
            publisher1: self.publisher1,
            publisher2: self.publisher2,
            subscriber: subscriber)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
}


let publisher1 = [1,2,3,4,5].publisher
let publisher2 = [300,400,500].publisher

let newPub = InterleavedPublisher(publisher1: publisher1, publisher2: publisher2)
let subscription = newPub.sink { print($0) }

print("---")

let anotherPub = InterleavedPublisher(publisher1: publisher2, publisher2: publisher1)
let anotherSubscription = anotherPub.sink { print($0) }
```

prints

```
1
300
2
400
3
500
4
5
---
300
1
400
2
500
3
4
5
```